# Creating a chat table in database from 2 separated tables

Tags: laravel, database, react-native, foreign-keys, chat

I have two tables in my database: 'customers' and 'store_owners'. These tables have a many-to-many relationship. I want to create a chat feature between the 'store_owner' and their customers. However, I encountered a problem when I created a 'chat' table in my database. This table includes 'IdSender', 'IdReceiver', and 'message'. Both 'IdSender' and 'IdReceiver' are foreign keys from the previously mentioned tables. However, in the same conversation, a customer can be both a sender and a receiver, and the same applies to the store owner. What should I do? Please note that the 'customers' and 'store_owners' tables must remain separate. I am using React Native and Laravel.

I attempted to create two foreign keys for the same ID, but as expected, it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

In the structure you describe there are no unique senders and receivers, as that would be a one way chat, instead there only chats, chat members and messages.

So create a chats table, create a chat_members (chat_id, user_id) pivot table, assuming both customers and store_owners relate to a user, if not use a morph many relation, linking the chat to however many users are in your chat. And a chat_messages (chat_id, sender_id, message) table. Whenever a message in sent to a chat, all members of that chat should receive the message.